# Android get View values from XML at runtime

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a Coordinator Layout containing layouts,views and a FAB. The problem is that the layout at runtime is invisible. At a specified event I have to

1. get it's position and margins (or size and margins - then position can be calculated from screen size...)
2. change it's visibility using main_fab.show()

My layout file:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_containter">
<!-- omitted -->
<Layout1>
    <!-- omitted -->
</Layout1>
    <!-- omitted -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/main_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"                
            app:srcCompat = "@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_outline_black_24dp"
            />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In code I tried the following:

```
//... code block

var mFabWidth=0
var mFabHeight=0

//... code block

    fun getCurrentFabValues(){
      mFabWidth=main_fab.width
      mFabHeight=main_fab.height
      /* and I also need it's default size and margin values */
    }
```

Since at the specified moment the FAB is invisible, main_fab.width and main_fab.height returns 0. Moreover I don't know how to get margin and default size. 
Can somebody please help how should I retrieve those values from XML?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use getWidth() and getHeight() .. also FAB should be visible if you want to get it's width and height

Comment: @twenk11k thank you but showing the FAB is part of an animation. It's visibility is triggered when animation completes, so this solution is not suitable in this exact case.